# Как найти смежные рёбра в графе?

Tags: python, графы, networkx

Можно ли, используя библиотеку NetworkX, найти смежные рёбра в графе, то есть рёбра с общей вершиной, если задать вершину, например?

Или узнать рёбра, смежные с данным ребром, например, зная вершину и это ребро?

Это необходимо для реализации алгоритма раскраски рёбер, т.к. смежные рёбра должны иметь разный цвет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.karate_club_graph()
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
список ребер смежных вершине `5`:

```
In [231]: G.edges(5)
Out[231]: EdgeDataView([(5, 0), (5, 6), (5, 10), (5, 16)])
```